# Usage of ostensible in this sentence

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

```
An obscure term ostensibly referring to a lung disease caused by silica dust.
```

***ostensible: stated or appearing to be true, but not necessarily so.***

Does ostensible in this sentence mean that there is another definition for the term?

**Update**:
Sorry for the ambiguity, What I'm trying to ask here is not the lexeme of "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"but the interpretation of ostensible in this sentence.

Comment: Maybe they allude to the accusation that the term was invented purely to be a very long (if not longest) word.

Comment: It probably rather means that there are a lot of cases that claim that's what the word means, but no real cases of the word actually be used to mean that (or anything else, for that matter).

Comment: I think the major 'accepted' usage was to achieve a long word on a certain quiz show. If it were a necessary term in real life, it would certainly be abbreviated. The patient might have died by the time his disease was written down.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth LOL

Comment: @MouseHello Shouldn't it be ...nonultra... ? Or does the 'no' belong to 'pneumono', which looks strange to me ...

Comment: @LeonConrad Yes, it belongs to "pneumono" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pneumono-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of obscure and ostensibly together in this sentence gives an almost perjorative sense to imply that the word is jargon.

I take it that you did not find this definition in a medical textbook.

Comment: Not just jargon, but rather unlikely at all: it contains *ultramicroscopic* which wouldn't normally appear in the middle of such a word.

Answer (score 0):

Though the word can be found in some dictionaries (just Google the word to find that out), its legitimacy as a word is disputed.

One online [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis) defines it as:

> An artificial long word said to mean a lung disease caused by inhaling very fine ash and sand dust.

The word's [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis) mentions that the word was coined, not by the medical community, but by the Will Shortz of his day:

> This word was invented in 1935 by Everett M. Smith, president of the National Puzzlers' League, at its annual meeting.

I don't think the word has much relevance outside the realm of trivia buffs and antidisestablishmentarianists, which is why the word has an *ostensible* definition.